# Changing WHMCS header titles on product configuration pages?

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs

This is what I currently have as my title in header.tpl in my WHMCS template:

```
<title>{$companyname} - {$pagetitle}{if $kbarticle.title} - {$kbarticle.title}{/if}</title>
```

However, I can't figure out how to make the title appear different when people are configuring a product.  For example, if someone is at http://portal.mysite.com/cart.php?a=confproduct&i=1

Then I would want the title to show the name of the product they are configuring.  So, instead of showing the above title, it should show "Level 1 Package" if that's the name of the product.  I keep playing around with the title but nothing seems to be getting this right, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

there are a variable called "groupname" in cart.php that refers to your product group, so you can just add this on your header.tpl

```
<title>{$companyname} - {if $groupname}{$groupname}{else}{$pagetitle}{/if}{if $kbarticle.title} - {$kbarticle.title}{/if}</title>
```

tested and worked for me

Comment: Do you know where can I find the list of all variables like "{$groupname}" ?  By the way, thanks a lot +1

Answer (score 0):

I found another way that worked for me.

You just have to add it to the language file.

I too want to change portal home so I added a custom name line in language file like so

Before:
$breadcrumbnav = ''.$_LANG['globalsystemname'].'';

so i looked for globalsystemname in language file and sure enough in said this:
$_LANG['globalsystemname'] = "Portal Home";

AFTER

so I added a line like so:
$_LANG['globalsystemnamehome'] = "Home";

and changed the line in the newpage.php like so:
$breadcrumbnav = ''.$_LANG['globalsystemnamehome'].'';

now it says "Home" instead of "Portal Home"